# rsyslog: action suspended, next retry is

Tags: networking, logging, rsyslog, systemctl, centralized-logging

I'm trying to configure `rsyslog` to receive logs sent from other devices on port 3100 (my manager chose that port and I will get him to change it to 514 later), and save (append) those logs in local files.  So I created `/etc/rsyslog.d/remote.conf` thus:

```
$umask 0000
template(name="DynFile" type="string" string="/var/log/remote/%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%")
ruleset(name="RemoteMachine"){ action(type="omfile" dynaFile="DynFile" dirCreateMode="0755") }

# provides UDP syslog reception
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="3100")

# provides TCP syslog reception
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="3100")

#Enable sending system logs over UDP to rsyslog server
*.* @rsyslog-ip-address:3100

#Enable sending system logs over TCP to rsyslog server
*.* @@rsyslog-ip-address:3100

#Set disk queue when rsyslog server will be down:
$ActionQueueFileName queue
$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on
$ActionQueueType LinkedList
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1
```

added debuggery to the `systemd` unit:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -d
```

then restarting `rsyslog`:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

then reviewing the port bindings:

```
# ss -tulpn|grep 3100
udp    UNCONN     0      0         *:3100                  *:*                   users:(("rsyslogd",pid=11899,fd=5))
udp    UNCONN     0      0        :::3100                 :::*                   users:(("rsyslogd",pid=11899,fd=6))
tcp    LISTEN     0      25        *:3100                  *:*                   users:(("rsyslogd",pid=11899,fd=7))
tcp    LISTEN     0      25       :::3100                 :::*                   users:(("rsyslogd",pid=11899,fd=8))
```

so it looks like `rsyslog` is listening as per the configuration file;  however, the last few lines of `journalctl -e -u rsyslog` are:

```
Sep 05 16:10:22 office-zabbix-proxy systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Sep 05 16:10:22 office-zabbix-proxy liblogging-stdlog[11899]:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0" x-pid="11899" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Sep 05 16:10:22 office-zabbix-proxy systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Sep 05 16:10:22 office-zabbix-proxy liblogging-stdlog[11899]: action 'action 1' suspended, next retry is Mon Sep  5 16:10:52 2022 [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Sep 05 16:10:22 office-zabbix-proxy liblogging-stdlog[11899]: action 'action 2' suspended, next retry is Mon Sep  5 16:10:52 2022 [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
```

I presume these 'actions' correspond to the two module/input declarations in the configuration file, but I have no idea why they have been 'suspended', whether or not it matters, and what I should do about it.

However, there are no files under `/var/log/remote/` (which exists, with 0777 permissions) so I presume something is stopping the configuration from doing what I want.  The OS is Debian 11 and is not in SELinux mode.  Help please?

Comment: This is all totally obvious to those that understand rsyslog configuration, but the lines starting `*.*` are in the so-called obsolete legacy system and are rewritten as `action()` lines by rsyslog upon startup, so that's from where the _action 1_ etc. logging arises.